Fix "The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type" error (feel free to come up with a better title)
Let me know if a single SOQL is possible for my use case.

Sales Order (object A)

Invoice (object B)

Invoice Line Item (object C)





My goal is to calculate a totals on Sales Order (object A) in case of Invoice Line Item (object C) modification.
As I don't need this calculation sync, I decided to go with future for this. Meaning I want to have a method that receives a list of Invoice Line Item (object C) Ids and updates all their Sales Orders (object A).
The logic is simple. On the Invoice Line Item I have a lookup to Invoice. Invoice has a lookup to Sales Order. I need to query ALL Invoices for a particular Sales Order to calculate Total Amount.
I don't want to deduct "old" amount of Invoice Line Item and add "new" amount because I want this method to be available elsewhere; and also it could be executed from anonymous and recalculate totals.
So I need to query all Invoices that are related to Sales Order. I have Invoice Line Item Id. I can SOQL Invoice object with Sales Order field and store the Sales Order Ids.
List<InvoiceLineItem__c> invoiceLineItemList = ...

Set<Id> invoiceIdsToProcess = new Set<Id>();
for (InvoiceLineItem__c iliItem : invoiceLineItemList) {
    invoiceIdsToProcess.add(iliItem.Invoice__c);
}

Set<Id> salesOrderIdsToProcess = new Set<Id>();
for (Invoice__c iItem : [
    SELECT SalesOrder__c
    FROM Invoice__c
    WHERE Id IN :invoiceIdsToProcess
]) {
    salesOrderIdsToProcess.add(iItem.SalesOrder__c);
}

List<AggregateResult> totalDepositAmountAR = [
    SELECT SalesOrder__c, sum(TotalInvoice__c) totalAmount
    FROM Invoice__c 
    WHERE SalesOrder__c IN :salesOrderIdsToProcess
    GROUP BY SalesOrder__c
];

The
List<AggregateResult> totalDepositAmountAR = [
    SELECT SalesOrder__c, sum(TotalInvoice__c) totalAmount
    FROM Invoice__c 
    WHERE SalesOrder__c IN (
            SELECT SalesOrder__c
            FROM Invoice__c
            WHERE Id IN :invoiceIdsToProcess
        )
];

gives me
Error: The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type
Is there any chance I can avoid using salesOrderIdsToProcess variable?
